# Javascript - How to add multiple objects into an empty array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add multiple objects- Company Names into listBox Companies. I used `$scope.companies.push(newCompany[0].name);` to add the company into the list. But only the first object's company gets added because I used `newCompany[0].name`.

Now, how do I add the second company name into the list without entering `newCpmpany[1].name` ? Say there are 50 companies, I cannot add all 50 by doing this. Is there a better way to add all the names in one go? like a loop or incrementing the element or something? Looking for some help. Thanks in advance.

```js
var newCompany = [{
            name: "Huawei", // -->COMPANY NAME
            email: "Drath@yahoo.com",
            phone: "123-123-1234",
            owner: "Drath",
            street: "Gin Blvd",
            city: "Austin",
            country: "USA",
            duns:"123112321",
            type: "buyer"
        },
        {
            name: "Asus", // -->COMPANY NAME
            email: "Vadar@yahoo.com",
            phone: "999-123-8888",
            owner: "Vadar",
            street: "Vince Blvd",
            city: "Dallas",
            country: "USA",
            duns: "123100000",
            type: "supplier"
        }];
        
        window.localStorage.setItem("newCompany", JSON.stringify(newCompany));
```

```js
$scope.companies = [];
    var newCompany = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCompany"));
    $scope.companies.push(newCompany[0].name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
$scope.companies.push(...newCompany.map(item => item.name));
```

or why do you need exactly push? why don't you just init `$scope.companies` with exact values

```
var newCompany = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCompany"));
$scope.companies = newCompany.map(item => item.name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! What code should I use if I need the new names it to an existing companies array["Apple","Samsung"]; instead of an empty []; array?

Answer (score 3):

If spread is not supported just a regular splice of array can be used

```
var names = newCompany.map(function(company){return company.name});
$scope.companies.splice(-1, 0, names);
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work. In the listbox, i need 2 options: Huawei and Asus. But this code puts both the names in a single option like: "Huawei, Asus" I need individual list options.